# Booting from USB devices on secure boot UEFI system

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, bios, gpt

I'm trying to put an ArchLinux install onto a USB-HDD and want it to be bootable on BIOS systems as well as on UEFI systems that use secure boot. Therefore I have one main question.

> Does an UEFI system with active secure boot permit or deny booting from USB drives?

According to [this article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#EFI_System_Partition) the UEFI partition holds all the bootloaders for the OSes on a physical drive and in my scenario that partition would already exist elsewhere on the system.

On the [Arch-Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR) I found this article on basic decisions to use rather MBR or GPT for partitioning on the boot device (also applicalbe on USB drives) and possible bootloaders are listed [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Boot_Loaders) but will any of these be recognized by the UEFI Firmware?

Comment: Are you asking about specific UEFI problems, i.e. how to make it work on systems that refuse to boot old style msdos/GRUB on USB? That's what worked everywhere for me so far...

Comment: Yes, perhaps I should refine my question. I don't have a UEFI system to test the final configuration. Right know I would make my partitions on a USB-HDD with GPT + the 2MB boot partition for GRUB and go with that. But what will happen when I plug the USB-HDD into a UEFI system? Will it permit booting or not? That's the question.